# re.findall not matching all matches

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse a large text file looking for patterns like this:

```
string='Path Group: sclk ;djlasfhv slack 5t45545 545 (VIOLATED)    -0.8568      Path Group: sclk ;djlasfhv slack (VIOLATED)       -0.88 Path Group: sclkasfhv slack (VIOLATED)                -0.121'
violation = re.findall('Path Group: sclk.*VIOLATED\)\s*(-[0-9]\.[0-9]+)', string)
```

This prints just the last -0.121. I am expecting [-0.8568, -0.88, -0.121]

P.S. I have just given a sample string here. The actual file is pretty huge. I am looking for all -ve numbers following the string in my regexp.

Whats the mistake I am making?

Comment: Nothing I can see except that `.*` which goes directly to the end of the string then starts backtracking, finding 1 match only (every time).

Answer (score 2):

Make it non-greedy. `.*` present in your regex is greedy which matches all the characters as much as possible. So this would match all and the `-[0-9]\.[0-9]+` pattern should capture the last number.

```
violation = re.findall(r'Path Group: sclk.*?VIOLATED\)\s*(-[0-9]\.[0-9]+)', string)
                                           ^
```

*Example:*

```
>>> import re
>>> string='Path Group: sclk ;djlasfhv slack 5t45545 545 (VIOLATED)    -0.8568      Path Group: sclk ;djlasfhv slack (VIOLATED)       -0.88 Path Group: sclkasfhv slack (VIOLATED)                -0.121'
>>> re.findall(r'Path Group: sclk.*?VIOLATED\)\s*(-[0-9]\.[0-9]+)', string)
['-0.8568', '-0.88', '-0.121']
```

Comment: Ah..Thanks!..Just learning python/regexes..not a software guy :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

A better and a more effecient regex than lazy matching is

```
violation = re.findall(r'Path Group: sclk[^V]*(?:V(?!IOLATED\))[^V]*)*VIOLATED\)\s*(-[0-9]\.[0-9]+)', string)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/uCFuAJ)

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fB9mE4/1)

It is based on [Jeffrey E. F. Friedl's "unrolling the loop" method](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop), and basically matches the same as the version with a lazy matching, but is more effecient:

- `Path Group: sclk` - literal sequence of characters
- `[^V]*(?:V(?!IOLATED\))[^V]*)*VIOLATED\)` - anything up to the first `VIOLATED)
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace
- `(-[0-9]\.[0-9]+)` - captures into Group 1 `-`, followed with a digit, then a period, and then 1 or more digits.

Comment: Maybe effeciency is not the bottleneck with the current input, but I fear the times when we just said "use lazy matching" or "do not be greedy" are coming to an end. Time to grow up.